# Is there a visualization tool that can inspect a Java code base and report inter-package dependencies?

Tags: java, uml, dependencies, package, static-analysis

We have a Java code base that has grown to be too big for a single monolithic JAR (more than 5000 classes).  One of the tasks that we are investigating is how much effort would it be to break this single JAR into smaller components with controlled dependencies between them.  However, it's somewhat hard to look at a big bag of code and be sure that you are finding the best points of separation without some analysis.

Are there good tools to inspect and visualize the interpackage dependencies?  Given those, we would have a set of suggested cut points where we could begin separating code.

As an example, in the days before Netbeans and Eclipse (and at a different job), we used TogetherJ and TogetherEnterprise.  Those had the ability to do a static package analysis and draw the UML diagram.  That sort of behavior would be optimal but that feature alone is not sufficient to justify the cost.

Comment: I think if you need a tool to tell you how to organize your 5000 classes, then you're in more trouble than such tool can pull you out of. Good luck.

Comment: @z5h, honestly?  Why wouldn't you use a tool to look for dependencies?  The output of such a tool is very useful for driving refactoring work.  Remember, this is the sort of thing that helps you identify nodes with weak mutual coupling.  Those nodes can then become candidates for separate deliverable build products.  Shorter build times for both, localized changes, etc., are all strong motivations for this sort of refactoring.  If there are tools that help point out "start here, this cut would be easy", why wouldn't you use such a thing?

Comment: I was just "commenting" that if you're at the stage where you have 5000 classes and there isn't enough of an application architecture to lead you in the right direction without a tool, then that sounds like a very bad situation. This is not an optimization exercise where a tool tells you what to look at next. This is the *entire architecture of your application*, which one should have a better handle on. If you are using the tool as verification of ideas, then that sounds good. If it's leading your design, that sounds scary. You made it sound like the tool would lead your design.

Comment: @z5h, no, the code is not the architecture.  The code is the implementation.  The architecture can draw the boxes with lines and say "this is the intended design."  An inspection tool can look through the code and ensure that none of the boxes on the architecture chart have a hidden connection when they shouldn't.  For example, a stray left-over "include" can introduce a dependency between two pieces of code that should never have been coupled but now have a hidden false dependency that affects build order.  The tool can inspect your code to make sure that it matches the architecture.

Answer (score 3):

I have recently discovered CodePro AnalytiX, formerly from Instantiations, now available for free from Google: 
https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/dependencies/dependencies

Answer (score 3):

[Intellij IDEA](https://web.archive.org/web/20150504130711/http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/dependency_analysis.html) has one:

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/70/dsm/dsmView2.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I used [stan4j](http://stan4j.com/dependencies/dependency-analysis.html) for the same purpose but unfortunately the community edition has a 500 classes limit. On the other side, it works as an eclipse extension.

Answer (score 1):

[SonarJ](http://www.hello2morrow.com/products/sonarj) is a good tool to do that, but it is expensive.

Another very good tool is [XDepend](http://www.xdepend.com/), which is cheaper. For your purpose, I would recommand you this tool. The best choice in terms of quality/price I think.

With much less functionalities, you can use a [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.com/) (Free and OpenSource) analysis and its dependencies matrix.

Answer (score 1):

[JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) is a free tool for analyzing package dependencies.

It identifies circular dependencies, which would impede breaking this monolith into smaller pieces.

We put this check for circular dependencies into our unit tests, to prevent them from the start.

There's a corresponding [Eclipse plug-in](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/jdepend4eclipse/).

You can send the output to GraphViz. However, the visualization becomes less understandable as the number of packages grows.

Now that CodePro AnalytiX [mentioned first by Fabian Steeg above] is free, it's worth another look. At least prior to purchase by Google, Instantiations reliably produced great software. I played with it some years back, and recall no complaints other than cost.

Answer (score 1):

A good try would be to reverse your jar file into a class diagram. I have found this tutorial which explain how to reverse project composed by jar files into UML class diagram: http://www.ejb3.org/jar_file_reverse/jar_file_reverse.html

You will be able to reverse at package level at see package relation but also to see clases from one package having relation to other packages. Once the project has been reversed you can reorganize it as a model and give this documentation to the implementation team.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do the classes use packages in a normal fashion or are all the classes in the same package?  If the first case is true, I'd consider writing a special-purpose tool to do the first cut.

Comment: the original architecture laid things out in a reasonable fashion.  However, years of customer requests and new development have lead to years of edits and it's time to wrangle all that back together.  5000 classes in one package would be gross, wouldn't it?

Comment: @bob cross - yes indeed.  I think I'd have to play with it for a while to determine even how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the kind of use case I build [degraph](https://github.com/schauder/degraph) for.

It allows you to define *slices*, i.e. sets of classes that belong together, and visualizes them as one collapsible node. You jars to be would be slices that you can tweak until they don't have any more cyclic dependencies, at which point they can become their own jar.

This makes it easy to spot dependencies between *slices* that you need to break. Since you can open the slice node and see all the contained classes it makes it also easy to identify possible refactorings (introducing interfaces, moving classes ..) to achieve you goal.